# How to fix an "error while loading shared libraries" issue with Claymore95?

Tags: scripts, libraries, shared-library

The terminal sequence leading to the error message is displayed below.

```
:~/Desktop$ cd /usr/local/claymore95
:/usr/local/claymore95$ sudo chmod u+s ethdcrminer64
:/usr/local/claymore95$ sudo nano mine.sh
:/usr/local/claymore95$ sudo chmod +x mine.sh
:/usr/local/claymore95$ ./mine.sh
epool: error while loading shared libraries: -epool: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

This is what the startup script looks like)

```
#!/bin/sh

export GPU_MAX_ALLOC_PERCENT=100

./ethdcrminer64 -epool us1.ethermine.org:4444 -ewal 
0xebf49ee69dab5522f40f6d093aa89bca7a7ad19c.Miner01 -epsw x -mode 1 -tt 68 -allpools 1
```

I am a complete newb when it comes to Ubuntu so please bear with me. I have been running Claymore95 from terminal without issue for quite a while until something changed when I was trying to find the keystore file to send ETH to another wallet from the geth account linked to Claymore. I assume I did something to cause the error, because after I stopped the miner to change the wallet address destination, and then restarted it, the error message listed above came up. I went back to the startup script, and changed the wallet address back to the original one, but when I restarted the miner the same error came up and has not changed since. I have searched this error on multiple sites, and the solutions are for the most part specific to the program so I am wondering if anyone can provide me with detailed instructions on how to reverse this issue? If I need to completely start from scratch with the program.

For what its worth, I also noticed solutions such as `ldconfig` working, but these solutions have not worked for me, once again I am assuming because the problem is application-specific.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming this is an issue with the command parameters, since you say you changed nothing else.

To confirm this, try running:

```
cd /usr/local/claymore95
./ethdcrminer64 -benchmark
```

If this runs without errors, move your parameters to config.txt. It should be relatively intuitive, as it should already exist, and contain some instructions. Remember to uncomment the parameters you want to set. Save the file, and make sure the filename is exactly config.txt and that it's located in the /usr/local/claymore95 folder. It could be a good idea to try the default (provided) config options in config.txt first.

When config.txt is set to the parameters you desire, you can run the ./ethdcrminer64 command without parameters:

```
./ethdcrminer64
```

If this is successful, change the last line of the startup script to just:

```
./ethdcrminer64
```

If this wasn't the issue, please edit your answer to include your logfile and I will take a look.

Comment: Thanks! The benchmark command returns the same shared libraries error with "-benchmark" in the place of "-epool". There is a config.txt document in the Claymore95 folder, but it only has a message in it, "# WARNING! Remove "#" characters to enable lines, with "#" they are disabled and will be ignored by miner! Check README for details." Unfortunately I don't know of which logfile you speak of. I know there are log files in the var folder and also in the claymore95 folder, but I did fail to mention that I deleted the original Claymore folder from local when the error first occurred to no avail.